# How can I Remove user access to the contents of WordPress admin menus?

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles, capability

I want to delete user access to some WordPress admin menus .

I use the following code, but this code only removes the menu links.

```
function remove_admin_menu() {
remove_submenu_page('edit.php','post-new.php');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_admin_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu' );
```

And the user can see the contents of the page by entering the menu address in the browser's address bar.

for example :

```
(domain)/wp-admin/post-new.php
```

I want the user to see the following message by entering the address in the browser ( for example ) :
your Access is Denied

What code should I use?

Comment: [Remove ability to access certain admin menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142517/remove-ability-to-access-certain-admin-menus)

Answer (score 1):

By WP_Role we can easily update the role by removing or adding new capabilities. Bellow a sample example for user role Administrator.

```
WP_Roles => array(
  'roles' => array(
    'administrator' => array(
      'name' => 'administrator',
      'capabilities' => array(
        'switch_themes' => true,
        'edit_themes' =>  true,
        'activate_plugins' => true,
        // Much more
      ),
      // Other roles
    ),
   'role_names' => array(
    'administrator' => 'Administrator',
     // Other role names
   )
   // ...
 );
```

You can get full understanding to go through official documents.

Here is the link of official documents of WordPress Role and Permission.
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/

Comment: Thank you . I know working with roles. And I know how to create a page in a menu and get capability to it .
We really need to create a new role? and set capability for it ? and set it for that user?
and how can get capability of menu admin ? is there an array ?
for example : what is gravity form capability ?

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Sneher will show you how to create a new role.

If your admin menu is custom then you can restrict the access in the register_taxonomy.

If your admin menu is pre-built by Wordpress then you will have to hook into the menu in the function file.